# setting php boolean to FALSE not working

Tags: php

I have no records in a table called assessment

I have a function:

```
function check_assessment_record($p_id, $a_id, $c){
    $dataexistsqry="SELECT * FROM assessments WHERE (pupil_id=$p_id && assessblock_id=$a_id)" ;
    $resultt = $c->query($dataexistsqry);
        if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) { 
            echo '<p>set $de = true</p>';
            $de=TRUE;
        }else{
            echo '<p>set $de = false</p>';
            $de=FALSE;
        }                   
        return $de;
        $dataexists->close();
}; //end function
```

I call the function thus:
`$thereisdata = check_assessment_record($pupil_id, $assessblock_id, $conn);`

However my function is printing out nothing when I was expecting FALSE. It prints out true when there's a record.

When I get the result in $thereisdata I want to check for if its TRUE or FALSE but its not working.

I looked at the [php manual boolean page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) but it didn't help

Comment: bugs: why do you echo out `true` on the false path? why are you trying to do close()` call **AFTER** you've returned from the function, meaning the close() is impossible to execute?

Comment: plus, you may also have a variable scope issue.

Comment: `()` is not for subqueries. they're not necessary, but they're perfectly legit ways of grouping a boolean test.

Comment: Why do I see "echo '<p>set $de = true</p>';" in the then AND in the else statement? Is it correct?

Comment: offtopic, but your call after the return wil not be reached.

Comment: yes, that is a mistake in the if statement.

Comment: the issue for me is more that the $thereisdate variable is set to TRUE when there is data but nothing when there isn't (so when I print it out I get TRUE or nothing)

Comment: I dont see the `$thereisdate` variable you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are passing the database connection as an object using the variable `$c` in your function parameter. This tells me that you would greatly benefit by creating a class and using private properties/variables. Also, there are many errors in your code that shows me what you are trying to achieve, some errors are the way you are closing your db connection using the wrong variable, or how you place the close connection method after the `return`, that will never be reached.

Anyway, I would create a database class where you can then call on specific functions such as the `check_assessment_record()` as you wish.

Here's how I would redo your code:

```
<?php

    class Database {

        private $conn;

        function __construct() {
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "root";
            $dbname = "test";

            // Create connection
            $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
        }

        function check_assessment_record($p_id, $a_id) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM assessments WHERE (pupil_id=$p_id && assessblock_id=$a_id)";
            $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo '<p>set $de = true</p>';
                $de = TRUE;
            } else {
                echo '<p>set $de = false</p>';
                $de = FALSE;
            }
            return $de;
        }

        function __destruct() {
            $this->conn->close();
        }
    }

    $p_id = 1;
    $a_id = 2;
    $db = new Database();
    $record = $db->check_assessment_record($p_id, $a_id);
    var_dump($record);

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. You are correct -there are silly errors in  my code - I posted in a hurry and when stressed - not good.

Comment: sorry to hear your stressed,  I can definitely relate. Let me know if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

are you using PDO's correctly?
A call for me would normally look like;

```
$aResults = array();

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->execute();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
   //do something, count, add to array etc.
   $aResults[] = $row;
}
// return the results if there is, else returns null
if(!empty($aResults)){return $aResults;}
```

if you didnt want to put the results into an array you could just check if a column is returned;

```
$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->execute();

if(! $st->fetch() ){
  echo 'there is no row';
}
```

Comment: but you are using the class for things like, `->query`, why not use the rest avaliable to you? Or do it all procedural?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
function check_assessment_record($p_id, $a_id, $c){
$dataexistsqry="SELECT * FROM assessments WHERE (pupil_id=$p_id && assessblock_id=$a_id)" ;
$resultt = $c->query($dataexistsqry);
    if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) { 
        echo '<p>set $de = true</p>';
        $de=TRUE;
    }else{
        echo '<p>set $de = false</p>';
        $de=FALSE;
    }                   
    return $de;
    $dataexists->close();
}; //end function
```

You can check the return value using if else condition as

```
$thereisdata = check_assessment_record($pupil_id, $assessblock_id, $conn);
if($thereisdata){ print_f('%yes data is present%'); }
else{ print_f('% no data is not present %'); }
```

The reason is , sometime function returning Boolean values only contain the true value and consider false value as null , that's why you are not printing out any result when data is not found.

Hope this will help you. Don't forget to give your review and feedback.